# Difference between standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml

Tags: java, jboss

What is the Difference between `standalone.xml` and `standalone-full.xml`. In what scenarios we use `standalone-full.xml`

Comment: I just copied your first sentence and paste it in my SEO and as second result got this: https://community.jboss.org/thread/199236 which shows in simple terms that the standalone-full.xml provides the complete Java EE 6 settings while standalone.xml does not.

Comment: If I have to use JMS, EJB then which xml file should I use?

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/174004

Answer (score 63, accepted):

- **standalone.xml**: Support of Java EE Web-Profile plus some extensions like RESTFul Web Services and support for EJB3 remote invocations
- **standalone-full.xml**: Support of Java EE Full-Profile and all server capabilities without clustering
- **standalone-ha.xml**: Default profile with clustering capabilities
- **standalone-full-ha.xml**: Full profile with clustering capabilities

Answer taken from: [The Differences Between JBoss EAP 5 and EAP 6](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2013/03/the-differences-between-jboss-eap-5-and.html)

Comment: there cannot be a better answer than this one!

Comment: **standalone-full.xml** is required for using **JMS**

Answer (score 13):

From RHELSM (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1136103)

1. **standalone.xml**: This is the default configuration file for a standalone server. It contains all information about the standalone server, including subsystems, networking, deployments, socket bindings, and other configurable details. This configuration is used automatically when you start your standalone server.
2. **standalone-full.xml**: This is an example configuration for a standalone server. It includes support for every possible subsystem except for those required for high availability.
3. **standalone-ha.xml**: This example configuration file enables all of the default subsystems and adds the mod_cluster and JGroups subsystems for a standalone server, so that it can participate in a high-availability or load-balancing cluster.
4. **standalone-full-ha.xml**: This is an example configuration for a standalone server. It includes support for every possible subsystem, including those required for high availability.

The server configuration for Messaging is contained in the *$EAP_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml* or *$EAP_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone-full-ha.xml* file for standalone servers. The  element in the server configuration file contains all JMS configuration.

It says, full config also include sub config:

- **standalone-full.xml** has **standalone.xml**
- **standalone-full-ha.xml** has **standalone-ha.xml**

Comment: How do we specify this in a  docker-compose file ?

Comment: With volumes, override with specific configuration

Answer (score 10):

If you configured `standalone-full.xml` instead of `standalone.xml`,- then you have to choose it while you start JBoss service.

`./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml`

If you do it in [JBoss Developer Studio](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/archive/2.1.0.GA/en/GettingStartedGuide/html_single/index.html#getting_started) then you should choose `standalone-full.xml` instead of `standalone.xml` in the Server Config.