# Differences Jboss standalone.xml vs standalone-full vs standalone-ha vs standalone-full-ha

Tags: java, xml, configuration, jboss, wildfly

What are the differences between Jboss standalone.xml vs standalone-full vs standalone-ha vs standalone-full-ha.

Thanks for your answers.

I tried standalone.xml and standalone-full, but I did not find a full explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524364/difference-between-standalone-xml-and-standalone-full-xml)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524364/difference-between-standalone-xml-and-standalone-full-xml